# Create migration files in rails from existing mysql table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I m developing an application in rails. I have created a table say "student" in mysql. Is there anyway to create its migration file in rails application? I have specified databse name in config/database.yml" and using others table too. But i want to create tables migration file. How can i do it?

Comment: I have specified databse name in config/development.rb  ?????

Answer (score 37):

- Start by referencing your existing MySQL database in database.yml
- run `rake db:schema:dump` to generate the *schema.rb* file
- Paste the `create_table` methods from your *schema.rb* into a new migration, and Voila!

Comment: I get this message: 'rake db:schema:dump  # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR'. What does it mean? I created a schema.rb file and rand the rake command again, but the same message appears. UPDATE: It seems that after getting that message, you need to run $rake db:schema:load

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo did you try without having the `schema.rb` file ? (rename it and try again). Also, can you run `rake` commands ?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo you're supposed to run `rake db:schema:dump` (without the `-T` flag. `-T` is used to tell you what a particular command does, that's why you're getting that output :) I corrected it in the answer.