# Generate New Rails App Using Existing Postgresql Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm used to creating new Rails apps and their schemas from scratch/scaffolding. However I need to hook up this app to an existing postgresql database in AWS that has never previously been hooked up to a rails app and contains a single table.

What's the best way to generate the rails app and model that will contain all of the columns in the database? I'm hoping there's a shortcut as opposed to manually writing a migration and copying each column name/type in.

Comment: You don't need any migration if the database is already there. You only need to create a model, tell the model the table name, and rails will automatically get the attributes of the model inspecting the table's columns. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions

Comment: But if you actually want to run a test/dev environment with a copy of the existing table you will want a migration to set it up. If its one single table I don't see why you think its a gargantuan task and just writing it manually is probably going to be faster than trying find a working tool to automate the task.

Comment: I agree with max... best approach is to create it as a new table as if it has never existed. Then migrate the data after you've created the table. Makes your life a lot easier if you ever want to make changes, or add columns.

Comment: Still an interesting question though... what if it was not one but 10 tables with relationships between them...

Comment: Seems there's already a thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164542/create-migration-files-in-rails-from-existing-mysql-table

Comment: Thanks guys - this gets me some good stuff to play around with!